# I don’t know if chi-squared is appropriate

Tags: chi-squared-test

I collected data among individuals-
I took noted screening results they had within the last year, collected a baseline screening, and another follow up 3 week screening.
I’m comparing the 3 screenings to determine changes (does more frequent screenings teach us anything?)

I’m thinking chi-squared? But not completely sure if that’s the best option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chi squared is used to test if the frequencies predicted by a model are consistent with the frequencies observed.  For example, if your model predicts that in a sample of 100 there should be 50 blue, 30 red and 20 green flowers, and you observer 55 blue 28 red and 17 green flowers... does the observed data fit the model.

If you don't have expected frequencies and observed frequencies then chi-squared is the wrong test.

It seems that your hypothesis is not "does the data fit the model" but "has the results of the screening changed" This suggests a t-test, or a non-parametric alternative such as Mann-Whitney U test. But you must be clear on why you are choosing a particular test; why the conditions required by the test are satisfied by your data. You can't try different tests until you get one that gives you the answer you want!

Comment: Thank you! I was wondering if t-test was appropriate, and I was overthinking it.